# On Google Cloud, deploy solution from service catalog via command line

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Here are the instructions how to do it from the UI:
https://cloud.google.com/service-catalog/docs/view-and-launch#launch_a_dm-based_solution

How can I do the same thing with the gcloud command line?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, we can deploy/launch a DM based solution from service catalog through User Interface(GCP console) but cannot launch through gcloud cli. However, there is a [data-catalog API](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/) for creating/searching the catalog but not for deploying/launching the solutions.